# join de 3 tablas sin duplicados sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql server:

```
  select  * from 
          MobileUsuario,
          MobileCliente,
          MobileLicencia
      where   
      MobileUsuario.IdCliente=MobileCliente.IdCliente 
      and MobileUsuario.IdCliente=MobileLicencia.IdCliente 
      and MobileLicencia.IdCliente=MobileCliente.IdCliente
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para eliminar los duplicados sin tener que usar distinct ???

Comment: puedes tu verificar con esta query si en verdad tienes duplicados ejemplo:
select nombre,count(*) from tabla group by nombre having count(*)>1

con esta query puedes ver que si tiene nombres duplicados.
espero que te ayude ahora no puedo ver la imagen para poner una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que no tienes repetidos, sino distintas combinaciones de filas entre distintas tablas. Por lo tanto, un DISTINCT no hará ninguna diferencia.

```
--Crear datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE MobileCliente(
    IdCliente int,
    NombreCliente varchar(100));
INSERT INTO MobileCliente
VALUES(1, 'Cliente 1')

CREATE TABLE MobileUsuario(
    IdCliente int,
    IdUsuario int,
    NombreUsuario varchar(100));
INSERT INTO MobileUsuario
VALUES(1, 10, 'Usuario 10'),
      (1, 20, 'Usuario 20'),
      (1, 30, 'Usuario 30');

CREATE TABLE MobileLicencia(
    IdCliente int,
    IdLicencia int);
INSERT INTO MobileLicencia
VALUES(1, 100),
      (1, 200),
      (1, 300);

--Consultas sin y con Distinct      
SELECT  * 
FROM MobileUsuario  mu 
JOIN MobileCliente  mc ON mu.IdCliente = mc.IdCliente
JOIN MobileLicencia ml ON mu.IdCliente = ml.IdCliente;

SELECT  DISTINCT * 
FROM MobileUsuario  mu 
JOIN MobileCliente  mc ON mu.IdCliente = mc.IdCliente
JOIN MobileLicencia ml ON mu.IdCliente = ml.IdCliente;

GO
--Descomentar para borrar tablas en area de pruebas
--DROP TABLE MobileCliente, MobileLicencia, MobileUsuario;
```

Para poder solucionar el problema, necesitas definir como se van a relacionar las múltiples filas de un mismo cliente de la tabla de usuarios con las múltiples filas de un mismo cliente de la tabla de licencias y que pasará cuando su número no coincida. Eso es ya un problema de reglas de negocio que tienes que resolver antes de pedir alguna solución en el código.

Dejo también un ejemplo de como sería si hubiera una relación entre filas de usuarios y licencias.

```
--Crear datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE MobileCliente(
    IdCliente int,
    NombreCliente varchar(100));
INSERT INTO MobileCliente
VALUES(1, 'Cliente 1')

CREATE TABLE MobileUsuario(
    IdCliente int,
    IdUsuario int,
    NombreUsuario varchar(100));
INSERT INTO MobileUsuario
VALUES(1, 10, 'Usuario 10'),
      (1, 20, 'Usuario 20'),
      (1, 30, 'Usuario 30');

CREATE TABLE MobileLicencia(
    IdCliente int,
    IdUsuario int,
    IdLicencia int);
INSERT INTO MobileLicencia
VALUES(1, 10, 100),
      (1, 20, 200),
      (1, 30, 300);

--Consulta con condición adicional.

SELECT  * 
FROM MobileUsuario  mu 
JOIN MobileCliente  mc ON mu.IdCliente = mc.IdCliente
JOIN MobileLicencia ml ON mu.IdCliente = ml.IdCliente 
                      AND mu.IdUsuario = ml.IdUsuario;

GO
--Descomentar para borrar tablas en area de pruebas
--DROP TABLE MobileCliente, MobileLicencia, MobileUsuario;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola con **igualar las claves de cada tabla** deberia bastarte de la siguiente forma

```
select  * 
from 
        MobileUsuario,
        MobileCliente,
        MobileLicencia
where
        MobileUsuario.IdCliente=MobileCliente.IdCliente 
        and MobileCliente.IdCliente=MobileLicencia.IdCliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que en la consulta el operador * significa que seleccionas todos los resultados de la tabla o tablas cuando haces joins como es tu caso, no se alcanzan a percibir los demás datos de tu consulta en la imagen que nos pasaste pero estoy casi seguro de que alguno de los datos es diferente entre cada tupla (generalmente los ID´s de las tablas) y recuerda que con un solo dato diferente es una nueva tupla por eso parece como si se repitiera, te recomiendo filtrar tu selección únicamente por los datos que necesites:

```
select   

MobileUsuario.idUsuario,
ModileUsuario.Activo
/* Y cualquier otro atributo de las otras tablas que necesites*/
from 
          MobileUsuario,
          MobileCliente,
          MobileLicencia
      where   
      MobileUsuario.IdCliente=MobileCliente.IdCliente 
      and MobileUsuario.IdCliente=MobileLicencia.IdCliente 
      and MobileLicencia.IdCliente=MobileCliente.IdCliente
```